# How old were Storm and T'Challa when they met for the first time?

Tags: marvel, comics

How old was young T’Challa when he met Storm on his walkabout?

Storm was said to be just 12 years old but what about Black Panther?

This was published in Marvel Team ups #100 and storm comics mini series

Comment: Off topic, but it saddens me how we won't be able to see that storyline unfold in the MCU.